# Accessing to a mtarix value and change it - Numpy Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, numpy

I am currently trying to create a 10x10 matrix I[i,j], which has value zero in all their positions, except those in which i and j are even. In these cases the value should be i*j.

The code I wrote does not work.

```
I = np.zeros ((10,10), dtype=int)
for i in I:
    for j in I:
        if i%2==0 and j%2 ==0:  # error shown here
            I[i][j]=i*j
```

Is this not possible when accessing to a matrix?

I've tried also with:

```
...
    if np.all (i%2==0 and j%2 ==0):
...
```

I read I can use np.nditer to access the matrix, but I don't know how to identify if i and j positions are even.

```
for i in np.nditer(I, order ='F'):
```

Comment: Stay away from `nditer`.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you're looping over the values in I (which are arrays), you need to loop over the indices with range:

```
I = np.zeros ((10,10), dtype=int)
for i in range(len(I)):
    for j in range(len(I[i])):
        if i%2==0 and j%2 ==0:  # no error shown here ~anymore
            I[i][j]=i*j
```

Now the error should go away

Answer (score 0):

```
In [81]: I = np.zeros((3,3), int)
In [82]: I
Out[82]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

Look at what happens during the iteration:

```
In [83]: for i in I:
    ...:     print(i)
    ...:     print(i%2==0)
    ...: 
[0 0 0]
[ True  True  True]
[0 0 0]
[ True  True  True]
[0 0 0]
[ True  True  True]
```

`i` is not the indices, but rather a "row" of `I`.  So it doesn't make sense to do the `%2` test, even though it does work.

You didn't show the error, but it probably is the `ambiguity` one.  You can't use an array like `[ True  True  True]` in an `if` statement, or with the Python `and`.

Lets expand your example to a double iteration:

```
In [84]: arr = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
    ...: for i in arr:
    ...:     print(i)
    ...:     for j in i:
    ...:         print(j)
[0 1 2]
0
1
2
[3 4 5]
3
4
5
```

===

As https://stackoverflow.com/a/66445682/901925 shows, a straight forward way to construct this array is to iterate on `range`, the index numbers, not the array elements or rows.

```
In [103]: I = np.zeros ((10,10), dtype=int)
     ...: for i in range(len(I)):
     ...:     for j in range(len(I[i])):
     ...:         if i%2==0 and j%2 ==0: 
     ...:             I[i][j]=i*j
     ...: 
In [104]: I
Out[104]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  4,  0,  8,  0, 12,  0, 16,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  8,  0, 16,  0, 24,  0, 32,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 12,  0, 24,  0, 36,  0, 48,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 16,  0, 32,  0, 48,  0, 64,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

While this may not be fastest or most idiomatic for `numpy`, it's essential that you understand why this works, and your code does not.  That's basic Python iteration.

A way to do the same, but with `numpy` arrays:

First makes an array of indices:

```
In [106]: x = np.arange(10)
In [107]: x
Out[107]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Identify the ones that you want to be 0:

```
In [108]: x%2!=0
Out[108]: 
array([False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False,
        True])

In [110]: x[x%2!=0]=0
In [111]: x
Out[111]: array([0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0])
```

Now use that array to make the `i*j`:

```
In [112]: x[:,None]*x
Out[112]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  4,  0,  8,  0, 12,  0, 16,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  8,  0, 16,  0, 24,  0, 32,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 12,  0, 24,  0, 36,  0, 48,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 16,  0, 32,  0, 48,  0, 64,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

With `::2`, everyother slicing, we can extract all the even index elements:

```
In [113]: Out[112][::2, ::2]
Out[113]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  4,  8, 12, 16],
       [ 0,  8, 16, 24, 32],
       [ 0, 12, 24, 36, 48],
       [ 0, 16, 32, 48, 64]])
```

That suggests another way:

Use the 2 step to construct the even-index values:

```
In [115]: x = np.arange(0,10,2)
In [116]: x
Out[116]: array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])
```

and use those to fill  in `I` values:

```
In [117]: I = np.zeros((10,10),int)
In [118]: I[::2, ::2] = x[:,None]*x
```